# gcd and lcm functions are not working in Vs code editor having mingw

Tags: c++, c++17, std, mingw-w64

I have g++ version 6.3.0 installed in my windows and I learned that gcd and lcm are available in c++17 does it supports c++17 if no what should I do so that I can use gcd and lcm in code I have tried 
but it didn't work.

Is there is any way I can upgrade my g++ version?

Comment: You can just install the new version. Unless you really need gcc you will probably find visual studio easier to use

Comment: @AlanBirtles how can i do it i need to code both in c++ and c but g++ version provided by mingw is 6.3.0.1.

Comment: According to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/95zb9v), gcc 7.1 seems to be the first version with `std::gdc()` support. Maybe, you think again about the hint with Visual Studio of @AlanBirtles. (I use Visual Studio in daily business and can very recommend it.) ;-)

Comment: How did you install mingw? Just do the same again but with the latest version